# Array cannot read property

Tags: javascript, axios

This is the problem

[image]

This is the script

```
var data = [];

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function (response) {
        data.push(response.data['0'])
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
console.log(data);
console.log(data['0'].body); //this is where I get the error
```

As you can see in the picture it should be correct but why I cannot read the property ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `data` object is filled when you try access it?

Does the following work?

```
var data = [];

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function (response) {
        data.push(response.data['0'])
        console.log(data['0'].body);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: I still got the error I tried that but still got wrong. Bdw Jonas W. is correct it was both equal.

Comment: With arrays, non-negative integers are indexes and keys (strings) that are non-negative integers will be treated as indexes. So, while this advice seems to resolve a problem accessing the array item, it really doesn't.

Comment: @JonasW. didn't know that, thanks! Updated answer.

Comment: It does console.log the exact value but why it doesnt print the value outside of axios?

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate answer.

Comment: @Colin, what is **axios**?

Comment: @Rahul https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score -1):

Your data is an array, so it must be accessed with integer like `data[0].body`.

String accessor might be useful for `Object` type, not array. For example, you can also do `data[0][“body”]`.

Comment: Wrong. `[1]["0"]` will return `1`

Comment: Property names are always strings (unless they are Symbols, but these aren't). `foo[0]` and `foo['0']` are completely equivalent.